# nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user

Tags: spring, jdbc

### I want to know the differences in the two ways to load jdbc.properties, look below

- No.1

  ```
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
  ```
- No.2

  ```
  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
          <list>
              <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
  </bean>
  ```
- When I use the No.1 method, appear a exception, below:

  ```
  nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'Mr SJL'@'58.48.110.168' (using password: YES)
  ```

  > and the ip is different from my Configuration:

  ```
  driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  
  url=jdbc:mysql://115.28.61.173:3306/WebSchool  
  username=******  
  password=******
  ```
- When I use the No.2 method, running successfully.
- So, why do they get a different result?